# How to Find Conjugates as Products of Disjoint Cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

So I have completed a question, but I have been asked to give my answers in the form of a product of disjoint cycles. My answers are:

$$
\rho_1 = (1 4 7 6 2 5), \: \rho_2 = (1 3 7 6 2 4 5)
$$

My question is, how can I possibly write these permutations as products of disjoint cycles?

Context: The question I'm answering is this,

$$
\text{Let}, \: \pi = (1 2 4 3)(5 6 7) \; \text{and} \; \sigma = (3 4 5 7)(1 2 6) \\
\text{Find an odd permutation} \; \rho_1 \; \text{and an even permutation} \; \rho_2 \; \text{such that}\\
\rho_1\pi\rho_{1}^{-1} = \rho_2\pi\rho_{2}^{-1} = \sigma
$$

Comment: Surely you have written each one as a product of disjoint cycles? There's only one element in the product.

Comment: Ah I see, is that valid? That a permutation with only one cycle counts as a product of disjoint cycles - as long as there is no repetition of course. If I understand what you've said?

Comment: Yes. You could if you wished add a second cycle $(3)$ to your version of $\rho_1$ but we usually suppress 1-cycles.

Comment: Thank you very much @ancientmathematician

Comment: You didn't say what symmetric group are those permutations of: $S_7$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, your results are already in the form of a product of disjoint cycles; optionally, you could add the cycle $(3)$ for the fixed point $3$ in the case of $\rho_1$.

Comment: Provided that we are in $S_7$. The OP didn't say anything about that.

Comment: @Devo: True – but if the authors of the question do as they say, they specified $\pi$ and $\sigma$ in the form in which the answer should be given, so if fixed points are to be included, it's $S_7$.